# Repository, live site, all in one same server

Tags: repository, redmine

Honestly, I don't really know how to begin.

I have a live site in a VPS. My development flow is usually making changes on my local machine, then pushes to live via capistrano. I use git, but I don't really know the setup (as it was done by a friend). So I am not sure my git repo is local, or in the server.

Now I wanna do something more manageable. I want to use Redmine to track my development. Having said this, I would like to host my repo in the same server as my live server. This can give easy access to the other remote developers. Is it a good idea to host this repo in a same server?

Also, in future, I will need to have a unit test and functional test server. I reckon this should be separated from the live server right?

What is a good arrangement? Of course I am pretty tight with budget, and I don't wanna buy my own physical server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hosted dev and live versions in the same VPS, e.g. dev.site.com. I usually make it basic auth to give at least a little privacy into its development. But if your source repository is also on the same VPS, then you need to have a standard backup process that gives you an off-VPS copy. You definitely don't want all your eggs in one basket.

For multi-developer use, you just need a repo that everyone can access. The dev instance is better split to the developer machines, plus a regular build cycle for dev version that includes everyone's changes. That would be your test/QA server. Unit tests can just be a local version.

Does that help? Not sure if this answer is as technical as you want.

Comment: It certainly does. All these web development flow seems to bother me. Any books that I can refer to?

Comment: Take a look at the Wikipedia Agile Development article. In general, I develop using Agile-type processes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development